# Why can't I know if the figure is a rectangle, if angles c+d=180 and c=d?

Tags: geometry, rectangles

I have a four sided figure, abcd (see the image, and ignore the EF part), where I know that angles c+d=180 and c=d.

[image]

However, this isn't enough information to decide if this is a rectangle - why is that?

Comment: $AB$ could be "tilted", with unequal angles.

Comment: Well...you still need to know something about $\overline {AB}$.  Is it parallel to $\overline {CD}$, say?  It's drawn as it it were, but maybe that's an accident.

Comment: This is the image given with the question, but nothing can be assumed based on the image except the number of sides and order of angles and nothing is to scale.

Comment: substitute the line EF on the right for BA.

Comment: Because it could be a right trapezium.

Answer (score 1):

Using euclidean geometry only, it is easy to find a figure which attends the given properties (4 sides with two adjacent angles which are equal and whose sum equals 180º).

Take a right trapezium for instance, it has all of the aforementioned properties yet it is not a rectangle.

[Trapezium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYAtY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here...we have made two parallel lines AD and BC;where CD is the shortest distance between those parallel lines
Hence,c and d both being 90 degrees; but we cannot say it is a rectangle until and unless we are not sure that even AB is the shortest distance...if AB is not the shortest distance...it will form a trapezium